# Volume of a part of a truncated pyramid

Tags: calculus, geometry, solution-verification, analytic-geometry, 3d

[image]

Given the rectangular pyramid $ABCDE$ with $A(-25, -15, 0), B(25, -15, 0), C(25, 15, 0), D(-25, 15, 0)$ and $E(0,0, 30)$, that is cut put the plane having a normal vector $(-1, -2, 3)$ and passing through $(0,0, 15)$.

The question is to find the volume of the parts of the pyramid on either side of the cutting plane.

My incomplete attempt, following the advice of **Calvin Lin** in his comment below, is as follows:

To calculate the volume of the upper part, first find the coordinates of points $P,Q,R,S,T$, then segment pentagon PQRST into three triangles: $\triangle SRQ , \triangle SQP, \triangle SPT $, let their areas be $A_1, A_2, A_3$ and the normal vector to the plane of $PQRST$ be $N = (-1, -2, 3)$, and let $h$ be the height of pyramid $PQRSTE$.  Further let $A_4 = [ATP]$, the area of $\triangle ATP$, then the volume of the upper part is given by

$ V = \dfrac{1}{3} ( h (A_1 + A_2 + A_3 )  + 30 A_4 ) $

Note that

$ h = \dfrac{ ER \cdot N }{\| N \|} = \dfrac{EQ \cdot N}{ \| N \| } = \dfrac{ EP \cdot N }{ \|N \|} = \dfrac{ ET \cdot N}{\| N \|} = \dfrac{ ES \cdot N}{\| N \|} $

I have carried out the above computations and got the volume of the upper part to be $V_1 \approx 2930.447315$.  From which I calculated the volume of the lower part by subtracting $V_1$ from the volume of the whole rectangular pyramid (which is $V_0 = \dfrac{1}{3}(50)(30)(30) $ ), and obtained the volume of the lower part as $V_2 = V_0 - V_1 \approx 12069.55268$

I look forward to your solutions to verify my answer.

Comment: Having posted several of this in the past day, I encourage you to think about how to break up the volume into various composite figures, that will allow for usage of just "volume of pyramid = 1/3 base area * height ", which could be used in all 3 of these questions. Also, please show your work, and not just state "I am looking for hints that I can work on, or complete solutions", which isn't welcome in MSE.

Comment: Thanks Calvin, advice taken.

Comment: I checked your result with GeoGebra: it is correct.

Comment: Thank you @Intelligentipauca

Comment: @Intelligentipauca If you still have the GeoGebra worksheet, can you share it in an answer.  I'll upvote and accept your answer.

Comment: Thank you for the kind offer, but I think your exposition above is just fine for the interested reader.